# How do I submit an issue in Python dev docs

Tags: python, code-documentation

I thought I noticed an error at:

https://devguide.python.org/compiler/

I poked around the devguide and found bugs.python.org, but it was not immediately clear how to highlight a quick item without becoming a contributor.

I looked for a Python community page to get help, but could not quickly find one.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can share the typo with the community without having to become a contributor, or of a better forum than stack to do find out?

Comment: What's the third function? It looks like the two functions are `_PySymtable_Build()` and `compiler_mod()`.

Comment: "If you would like to file an issue about this devguide, please do so at the [devguide repo](https://github.com/python/devguide/issues)." (https://devguide.python.org/tracker/)

Comment: Also, what's wrong with becoming a contributor? People would LOVE to have the chance to contribute to python. It's not a job, it's completely voluntary, you can do it once and never again. Although, as Kraigolas pointed out, the documentation seems to be all right, you just misunderstood it. You can still open an issue to suggest an unambiguous way to write that.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with being a contributor.  I would love to do that at some point when I have time.

Comment: The third function is _PyAST_Compile()

Comment: So does that call itself? If so, then your proposal should at least say so as well

Comment: You are correct!   I misread the ';' as a ','.     Such are the hazards of aging eyes.   I see it now.   Thanks all, for your help!

Comment: I removed my erroneous issue with the doc, but left the primary question in case others might want to learn how to contribute to the Python docs.   Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the "V: Latest" link at the bottom right of the page you linked, and go to GitHub -> Edit, you'll be taken to this page: https://github.com/python/devguide/edit/main//compiler.rst

Which says:

> **You need to fork this repository to propose changes.**
> Sorry, you’re not able to edit this repository directly—you need to fork it and propose your changes from there instead.

So, you can fork the repo, make the correction, then submit a pull request with your proposed changes.

Or, as was pointed out in a comment, the documentation you linked has a [page](https://devguide.python.org/tracker/) which says that you can file it as an issue on the repo's [issues page](https://github.com/python/devguide/issues).

**Of course, verify that you're raising a *valid issue* before submitting it so you don't waste the devs' time. A few comments on your post pointed out that the issue you think is there is not actually an issue at all.**

Answer (score 1):

Python guide is open source, you may do by making a pull request to python/devguide github. The page in question located at [compiler on python/devguide github](https://github.com/python/devguide/blob/main//compiler.rst)